# Eclipse not updating referenced libraries for my Play framework application

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

Since I'm eager to use Elastic Search in my Play 2 project I have read through 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/ and 
added the dependency:

Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "test"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",      
      "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "0.19.10"
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here
      resolvers += Resolver.url("GitHub Play2-elasticsearch Repository", url("http://cleverage.github.com/play2-elasticsearch/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)      
    )
}
```

The dependecy is found and downloaded, checking with play dependencies:

```
Here are the resolved dependencies of your application:

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Module                                                            | Required by                                             | Note                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.19.10                           | test:test_2.9.1:1.0-SNAPSHOT                            | As elasticsearch-0.19.10.jar       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:3.6.1                        | org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.19.10                 | As lucene-highlighter-3.6.1.jar    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:3.6.1                             | org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.19.10                 | As lucene-memory-3.6.1.jar         |
|                                                                   | org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:3.6.1              |                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:3.6.1                            | org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.19.10                 | As lucene-queries-3.6.1.jar        |
|                                                                   | org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:3.6.1              |                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:1.4                                 | org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:3.6.1                  |                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:3.6.1                          | org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.19.10                 | As lucene-analyzers-3.6.1.jar      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:3.6.1                               | org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:3.6.1                | As lucene-core-3.6.1.jar           |
|                                                                   | org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:3.6.1                  |                                    |
|                                                                   | org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.19.10                 |                                    |
|                                                                   | org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:3.6.1                   |                                    |
|                                                                   | org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:3.6.1              |                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.18                                 | test:test_2.9.1:1.0-SNAPSHOT                            | As mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| play:play_2.9.1:2.0.3                                             | test:test_2.9.1:1.0-SNAPSHOT                            | As play_2.9.1.jar                  |
...
```

But in eclipse I can't use elasticsearch since it can't find the libraries. I'm not
even able to import it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't want to downvote you, but there was many questions about Eclipse and Play on the Stack Overflow last days, please check it, most probably you'll find solution in some of them.

Comment: Did you redo an `eclipsify` in the Play console after adding your new dependency ?

Comment: Perfect! That was it! Write your answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to redo an `eclipsify` in the Play console after adding your new dependency (ie after updating your `Build.scala` file).

It will generate a new `.classpath` file for Eclipse containing your new dependency.

Comment: or 'play eclipse' for 2.x

Answer (score 1):

If there is Build.scala set up properly, and an info about required library found in newly-generated .classpath file, than try to run *play eclipsify* and if it works NOT, simply **restart Eclipse**. It worked for me.