# What's a sane workflow for (re)generating Eclipse project files in Java Play Framework?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, playframework

I can generate Eclipse files for a Play 2.1 project via:

```
$ play eclipse with-source=true
```

...  and then I can do File -> Import [Existing Project] in Eclipse.

That works great -- but when I want to add a dependency to `project/Build.scala`, I can't figure out how to get this to update in Eclipse.  The only working solution I have is:

1. Delete project from Eclipse
2. Re-run `play eclipse`
3. Re-import project into Eclipse

Which can't be "the right way." (**Or can it?**)

Related question (but addresses an older version of Play):
[Eclipse not updating referenced libraries for my Play framework application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727510/eclipse-not-updating-referenced-libraries-for-my-play-framework-application)

Comment: If, instead of importing source, you store the source outside your workspace and add a linked source folder to your project, does that work? I don't know anything about Play so, sorry if this isn't helpful, but using a linked source folder should show any changes to the directory structure or addition/removal of files in Eclipse automatically.

Comment: Source is still being stored outside of my workspace in the workflow described.  This may be a Play tooling-specific question.

Comment: What about the instructions here, which also mention a Play plugin for eclipse (are you using the plugin?): http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/ide

Comment: That's a help page for Play 1.2. The relevant page for 2.1 is: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/IDE (and there's no mention of a plugin).

Comment: One last try; what happens if you close and reopen the project, or clean it and explicitly refresh? Does it update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (using Eclipse Juno):

If you add a dependency, use the play console to reload the project:

```
[play] $ reload
```

Then rebuild the eclipse configuration:

```
[play] $ eclipse
```

Then refresh the project within eclipse by right clicking on the project and clicking *Refresh*.

There's no need to delete the project and create a new one.

Comment: I tried this with no luck (also Eclipse Juno) -- but good to know that it should/can work!

Comment: Additional random suggestions: have you tried also a `Project -> Clean`?  Do you have `Project -> Build automatically` turned on?

Comment: And I can confirm again this recipe works, as I just added a Hamcrest dependency to my project. Don't know what's up with your. :-\

Comment: Anyway, thanks -- marking as answered even though this isn't working for me.  Probably a local config anomaly.